# Sim800 interupt on ussd

Tags: arduino, avr, sim800

I am trying to execute some USSD commands with sim800 and store the result.
I need to enable `ring` interupt for USSD commands just like calls and sms.

Here is my Sim800 code for using ussd:

```
AT+CUSD=1,"[some ussd]",15
```

Please note that my code works fine without the ring interupt but I need a way to it with interupts.

Thanks

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @Juraj I need to be notified when does the ussd response arrives. And I can't use blocking code to wait for response.

Comment: and did you connect the RING pin?

Comment: @Juraj Yes it is connected and works fine for call/sms. But for USSD it seems not to work. I read the datasheet and forums about sim800 ussd commands. Still no chance.